# Регулярное выражение для URL

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста, немного изменить регулярное выражение (и можно ли такое вообще сделать?). Есть ругялрка:

```
/^(http|https|ftp):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)/i
```

Она требует, чтобы адрес сайта был примерно такой: **http://**site.ru, то что я выделил жирным - в этом загвозка. Дело в том, что этой части может и не быть. Скажите, как можно изменить выражение, чтобы url был валиден как с http, https, ftp, так и без него?

Comment: url без указания протокола - не url :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

наверное что-то вроде

```
/^((http|https|ftp):\/\/)?(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)/i
```

Comment: @Angus123, кстати, ваша регулярка профейлит русскоязычные доменные имена.

Comment: @kolpak, а ничего, что ваш регексп будет говорить OK на **любую** последовательность символов с точкой внутри? Например, на `1234.5678`, или `1.5`, или даже `o.o.o` :-) @eicto прав, нет протокола - и нечего обсуждать. Если, конечно, нет каких-то дополнительных условий, про которые нам ничего не сказано.

Comment: @klopp, это модифицированный регексп топикстаретра, а не мой :)
а по сути - да, вы правы, хотя мы не знаем условия задачи решаемой тс, возможно его регексп достаточен